# Rails 4.2 development server can't be reached Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed Rails 4.2 on a Ubuntu 14.04 VM to act as a development environment. When I start the rails server with `rails s` the server says it starts and is listening for connections on `http://localhost:3000`

If I try to access `<IP>:3000`, no page is displayed and nothing hits the logs of the rails server.  If I execute `curl localhost:3000` from within the machine, I get the html of my home page.

If I execute `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`, I can access the server by its IP address.

On my MacBook Pro, running `rails s` (listening to `localhost`) allows me to access the rails app via `localhost:3000` or `<IP>:3000`.

- Ubuntu 14.04.1
- Rails 4.2

Comment: You'll still need the port along with the IP address to access it.

Comment: @japed I wasn't clear in my question, sorry. I was accessing port 3000. Updated the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server

Rails 4.2 release notes say, that now default host for rails server is localhost.

So if you want to access app from another machine, use

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

Probably your Macbook Pro uses older Rails version, with old behavior

Comment: Thanks for the link to the release notes.  MacBook Pro is running the same version of rails (it's the same application), so not sure. Perhaps the MBP interprets localhost as the 0.0.0.0 host or something?

Comment: Maybe, but it is not a question for SO. The main idea, is that on ubuntu your rails server has a valid behavior.